# Exclude subproject in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have two library projects, A and B, both depending on a third library project C.

I am trying to use both A and B in my app project by having the following in my `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation project(':libraryA')
implementation project(':libraryB')
```

This works fine when creating a release build, but fails for debug ones with the following error:

```
> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug FAILED
D8: Program type already present: com.libraryc.SomeClass
```

It looks like it is fine to bring library project C twice in release because the names get obfuscated separately and there are no conflicts (since I have `minifyEnabled true` for release builds). However, this doesn't fly in debug.

Since both `libraryA` and `libraryB` require a dependency to `libraryC`, I guess the solution is to keep those dependencies but exclude one of them from the app's `app/build.gradle`. It's not clear to me how to do this.

I have read on how to exclude modules and groups, but doing something like:

```
implementation project(':libraryA') {
    exclude module: 'libraryC'
}
```

or

```
implementation project(':libraryA') {
    exclude group: 'com.libraryc'
}
```

doesn't work, as Gradle doesn't seem to recognize the commands (my guess it's because 'libraryC' is a project, not a module?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working was, in the `build.gradle` of `libraryA`, using `compileOnly` for `libraryC` if on debug mode and `compile` if in release mode.

My understanding of why this work is the following:

- In release mode both versions of `libraryC` are pulled from the app. Since they are both proguarded (obfuscated) there are no conflicts, as before.
- In debug mode only `libraryB`'s version of `libraryC` is pulled from the app. Since there is no proguarding here, `libraryA` can use the exported version from `libraryB` no problem.

In my case I can determine the build type by checking an environment variable which gets manually set as part of the whole build process, so this is what ends up in `libraryA`'s `build.gradle`:

```
if(System.getenv('DEBUG_BUILD') != "1") {
    compile project(':libraryC')
} else {
    compileOnly project(':libraryC')
}
```

Note that `DEBUG_BUILD` is an environment variable that I set myself when I launch a debug build, so do not expect this to work by simply copy-pasting into your project.